# Unable to attach to application 'iisexpress.exe' using ' '. Unrecognized error occurred in the Windows Web Services framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I always get this error :

> "Unable to attach to application 'iisexpress.exe' using '  '.
>   Unrecognized error occurred in the Windows Web Services framework."

when I try to debug asp.net web forms application and application doesn't stop at any break point set.

this errors appeared after selecting this option from Visual studio options :

> " use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects "

I selected this option as solution for 64 compatiabilty with oracle client.

I use Visual Studio Community 2015 version and tried all available online solutions but with no change ( reset visual studio settings , change registry values , ...)

any one has additional suggestion to solve this issue ?

Comment: How do you open your app, as a solution/project or as a web site? Have you ensured to run your vs2015 as an administrator?

Comment: I opened it as a solution contains a web site . I tried to open it as an administrator and in safe mode with no change.

Comment: How about other projects, are they running fine? Maybe it's a vs2015 issue, try to reinstall it.

Comment: No the same behaviour